# Boundary gradient estimate

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, differential-equations

Assume $U$ is the unit disk and $\bar U$ its closure and let  $u\in C^2(U)\cap C(\bar U)$ be a real function, with $u(z)=0$ for $z\in \partial U$. If $$|\Delta u|\le A|\nabla u|^2+g(z),$$ for some constant $A$ and $g\in L^p(U)$, $p>2$, then $|\nabla u|$ is bounded in $U$. How to prove this?

Comment: Is $u$ solution of a PDE, or just any function?

Comment: Is not a solution.